# Making a Function-Activated Link Appear Without Having to Refresh Browser

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the code below to make the `<a href='http://www...com/.../footervote.php'>Vote</a>` link appear if a user logs in and a user shows up in the function `getEditorsList()`.  The vote link only appears if the browser is refreshed.

Any idea how I could make the vote link appear without having to refresh the browser?

Thanks in advance,

John

index.php:

```
<?php 

 require_once "header.php"; 
 //content
 include "login.php";
 // more content
 require_once "footer.php";

?>
```

In header.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); 
session_start();
require_once ('db_connect.inc.php'); 
require_once ("function.inc.php"); 
$seed="0dAfghRqSTgx"; 
$domain =  "...com"; 

            $editors = getEditorsList();
            foreach($editors as $editor)
            {
            $editorids[] = $editor['loginid'];
            }

            if(in_array($_SESSION['loginid'], $editorids))
            {
            echo "<div class='footervote'><a href='http://www...com/.../footervote.php'>Vote</a></div>";
            } 


?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{

    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {

        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();


        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {

        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{

    show_userbox();

}



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you set $_SESSION['loginid'] after your in_array query? If you render header.php first, in_array returns false (although the session has been started, but loginid will be set a few lines down the road in login.php).

Move this:

```
        if(in_array($_SESSION['loginid'], $editorids))
        {
        echo "<div class='footervote'><a href='http://www...com/.../footervote.php'>Vote</a></div>";
        }
```

from header.php to login.php like this:

```
else {

    show_userbox();
    if (in_array...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the link is present but hidden you use some DHTML (JQuery / Scriptaculous) to set the display/visibility attributes correctly.

If the link is not present in the original html (preferable for security reasons) then when the login occures fire off an AJAX request that returns javascript that will insert the link in the correct location (parent element).